# CV2 Get specific frame instead of having to loop through entire video

Tags: python, opencv

I want to just extract a single frame from a video, but the method I have so far has to scan through the entire video to get to it.  If the video is long this takes a long time.  I have the following code put together:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(str(input_files[0]))
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
success,image = video.read()
count = 0
success = True

print("FPS: " + str(fps))

minutes, seconds = indexImageTimeStamp.split(':')

print('minutes: ', int(minutes))
print('seconds ', int(seconds))

targetFrame = int(minutes) * (60 * int(fps)) + (int(seconds) * int(fps))
print('targetframe ', str(targetFrame))

framecount = 0
while (framecount != targetFrame) and success:
    success,frame = video.read()
    framecount+=1
    # print(framecount)
else:
    # print('target frame reached')
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('path' 'indexframe.jpg'), frame)
    # print("time stamp current frame: ",count, " - ", round(count/fps, 2))
```

`video.read()` forces me to scan the entire video.  I know the frame I want to get to, `targetFrame`.  How to just get that frame only to save time and memory?

Comment: Have you tried `video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, targetFrame)` to seek the video and reading from there? That may work if the video is seekable.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule no I havent, I didnt know about that.  From what I gather from other stackoverflow posts though, CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES is not to be trusted?

Comment: correct. nothing is to be trusted. cv::VideoCapture makes no guarantees about seeking. if you need reliability, use ffmpeg directly, via PyAV. and implement seeking as ffmpeg requires it: seek to closest point, then decode until you are where you want to be.